# How to get the number of thread groups in test plan

Tags: jmeter

I have a small script that has it's own properties and a single Thread Group.  Sometimes I need to merge this test script into a bigger test plan that has more than a single Thread Group.  I need a way to say if there's only 1 thread group then apply these user defined variables.  Any ideas?  I'm thinking I would add an If Controller but I can't seem to find what condition I would put.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what I want to do will work.  It seems the User Defined Variables element inside the If Controller gets run regardless of the If condition....Basically if the script runs solo, I need to set certain variables but if it's merged and run in the bigger script, it should use the bigger scripts variables...hmm I'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

You can instead add If condition about your [TestPlan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__TestPlanName),
For example if your small script is 1.jmx check

```
 ${jexl3( "1.jmx" == "${__TestPlanName}")}
```

Also you can add a variable in Test plan as `amILong` with true value and check if it exists.

Comment: I'm not sure why both of these answers were voted down.  They both look like good answers that I will try now.  Thank you!

Comment: I could only change the vote to either 0 or -1.  Weird

Comment: you can only vote once, if someone voted down to -1, then you can upvote +1 to 0

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can get the number of Thread Groups in the Test Plan, but it will require some scripting assuming using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/).

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) somewhere to your Test Plan
2. Make sure `groovy` language is selected in "Language" dropdown
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine
   import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
   import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass
   import java.lang.reflect.Field

   def engine = ctx.getEngine()
   def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test")
   test.setAccessible(true)
   def testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine)

   def threadGroupSearch = new SearchByClass<>(ThreadGroup.class)
   testPlanTree.traverse(threadGroupSearch)
   def threadGroups = threadGroupSearch.getSearchResults().size()

   log.info('Detected ' + threadGroups + ' Thread Groups in the Test Plan')

   if (threadGroups == 1) {
       props.put('foo', 'bar')
   }
   else {
       props.put('foo', 'baz')
   }
   ```

If there is only one Thread Group in the Test Plan the above code will create `foo` JMeter Property with the value of `bar`, in the other case(s) the property value will be `baz`. You will be able to refer the property via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(foo,)}` where required, i.e. in the If Controller.

Demo:

[image: JMeter Count Number of Thread Groups]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)